# disable ssl for a specific page

Tags: .net, ssl, iis-6

ENVIRONMENT
IIS 6
.NET 3.5 (WEB FORMS

For various reason I would like to turn of SSL at a page level. Is this best practice? what should I look out for while I am doing this? What is considered the safest way to do this? The way I was going to do this was

right click on the page-> navigate to properties-> click file security->then uncheck require secure channel.

Will this effect other pages. Any help would be great thank you

Comment: Be careful about leaking information between pages when you switch to the clear protocol. For example, if the authentication token or session ID are passed in http headers, these could be visible when you switch to the pages in the clear. An attacker sniffing the network (see Firesheep - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep) could capture these headers when sent in the clear. So, if you do this, you have to make sure you aren't accidentally sending secure information on the clear pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: I am using `.aspx` to represent ASP.Net pages, but the following should apply in general.

Even if you uncheck require secure channel, I believe it will still use the secure channel (because you are telling it SSL is not *required*, but that doesn't mean it can't still use SSL).  For instance, if you navigate from secure_page1.aspx to unsecure_page2.aspx, it will navigate over HTTPS (or whatever protocol the first page used) by default, i.e., it won't automatically switch from HTTPS to HTTP when you click the particular page link.  The only way to do that is with absolute url links, i.e., on https://www.mydomain.com/secure_page1.aspx, you have a link on the page that says:

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/unsecure_page2.aspx">Link to unsecure page</a>
```

Personally, I would recommend that if a website requires any SSL pages, that the whole website be SSL, or entire sections of it (say the ordering system) be SSL rather than just individual pages that need to be secure.  A big gotcha here is to remember that any page that will send critical info must be SSL *before* the user enters the form.  For instance, don't make Login.aspx non-SSL, then Login-Post.aspx (the form post action url) SSL, because that is not secure.

I must admit I have done a project where the website was a mix of HTTP and HTTPS, and we wanted to force the user's browser to use the protocol we wanted.  The main reason for this is that HTTP pages are more efficient both on the server and browser than HTTPS, because the encryption adds overhead to each request.  I used the following (hackish) method for that project:

1. Every redirect / link is channeled through a helper method that is aware of which pages are supposed to be viewed as HTTP vs. HTTPS (this works only if you are using some server-side code, otherwise you will have to update all the links manually.)
2. If navigating from same protocol to same protocol (HTTP -> HTTP, HTTPS -> HTTPS), just emit / redirect normally (i.e., relative link)
3. If navigating from HTTP -> HTTPS, just emit / redirect normally, except use an absolute URL to change the protocol.
4. If navigating from HTTPS -> HTTP... this is the really hard one, because most browsers will display a warning message to the user if you just emit an absolute url link with the  protocol change.  You have to use a META-Refresh redirect.

I use a redirection helper page `redirect.aspx?url=unsecure_page2.aspx`, which basically emits a meta tag like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.mydomain.com/unsecure_page2.aspx">
You are being redirected to http://www.mydomain.com/unsecure_page2.aspx.
If you aren't redirected in 5 seconds, please click <a href="http://www.mydomain.com/unsecure_page2.aspx">here</a>.
```

Then when you are on https://www.mydomain.com/secure_page1.aspx, and you want to redirect to unsecure_page2.aspx, you use the redirect helper:

```
See unsecure page <a href="redirect.aspx?url=unsecure_page2.aspx">here</a>!
```

Comment: I tried using an absolute link `http://mysubDomain.MyDomain.com/unsecure_page2.aspx` but that generats a "The Page must be viewed over a secure channel" error

Comment: @gh9: If you are going to use my method, then you will still need to uncheck "require secure channel" for every page that should be viewed over HTTP (or disable for entire site and handle purely through business logic).  If you want to make sure nobody can visit a page directly over HTTP even with "require secure channel" unchecked, you can manually run code on the page that checks if the page is HTTP, and if so, automatically redirects to HTTPS.